# Do I need a visa to go out of the airport in Seoul for sightseeing?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, mongolian-citizens

I'm going to Mongolia and have a 14-hour layover in Seoul with Asiana Airlines from the USA. Do I need a visa to go out of the airport for sightseeing? I'm a Mongolian passport holder.

Comment: It's only a duplicate if Mongolian citizens and Vietnamese citizens fall under _identical_ rules in South Korea.

Comment: @WGroleau However the answer answers the OPs question. (Mongolia would normally require a VISA, unless the OP already has a valid US VISA.

Comment: The ROK government website also says Mongolians with "diplomatic, official" passports don't need a visa.  But for other countries, it's "ordinary, diplomatic, official"  I don't quite get how a passport can be not an official passport.  But apparently "ordinary" and "diplomatic" and not "official."

Comment: @WGroleau An "official" passport is a type of passport issued by many countries to government officials traveling on official, but not diplomatic, business. Diplomatic status is controlled under the Vienna Convention on Diplomatic Relations and is limited to accredited diplomats. Official passports might be issued to government personnel stationed overseas or attending intergovernmental meetings. Since these passports are issued under different circumstances than ordinary passports, some countries will have different visa policies for them

Comment: Oh, a passport for officials.  As opposed to an official passport for a non-official person.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for nationals of **any country** with a visa issued by [...] USA [...] if in transit through
>     Korea (Rep.) must: 
>     -hold confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>     30 days; when [...] **arriving from the country that issued the visa and
>     departing to a third country**

So no, you do **not** need a visa